# Returning from 2 different activities. How to know where I came from

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

so I have an activity that returns leads me back to the main activity with an Int. the tricky part is that there are 2 ways to get back. either return with a location id or return with a route id. if it returns with a location id, it'll create a marker on the map. However, if it returns with a route id then it draws a line on the map. My problem is that i don't have any way of knowing if i returned to the main activity with a location id or a route id.

```
if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_BOOKMARKS_ACTIVITY)
    {
        if(data != null)
        {
            if(// Check if it's a location id)
            {
                int locationId = data.getIntExtra(BookmarksActivity.LOCATION_ID, 1);
                Log.i("BBB",    locationId + "");
                myDataSource.open();
                com.zayed.zma_at3.model.Location savedLocation = myDataSource.getLocationByID(locationId);
                createMarkerOnLocation(savedLocation.getTitle(),savedLocation.getLat(),savedLocation.getLng());
            }
            else
            {
                int routeId = data.getIntExtra(BookmarksActivity.ROUTE_ID, 1);
                myDataSource.open();
                Route route = myDataSource.getRouteById(routeId);
                route.setLocationPoints(myDataSource.getPointsByRouteId(routeId));

                // Draw line on map
                for(com.zayed.zma_at3.model.Location p : route.getLocationPoints())
                    {
                        Log.i("BBB",  route.getId() +" "+ p.getId() + " " + p.getLat()
                                + " " + p.getLng() + "");
                    }
            }
        }
```

and this is where i return from 
Location:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra(BookmarksActivity.LOCATION_ID,locationID);
                intent.putExtra(BookmarksActivity.BOOKMARK_TYPE,1);
                ((Activity) context).setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                ((Activity) context).finish();
```

Route:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra(BookmarksActivity.ROUTE_ID,routeID);
                intent.putExtra(BookmarksActivity.BOOKMARK_TYPE,2);
                ((Activity) context).setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                ((Activity) context).finish();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you put your location id on the intent extras also add the route id as -1 (or something that's not valid in your scenario anyway) and vice versa. When you check for your activity result, do something like:

```
   //if the location id is not equal to -1
if (data.getIntExtra(BookmarksActivity.LOCATION_ID, -1) != -1) {
   // it means that there is a location id so do what you want with that
}
```

same with your route id

EDIT to include code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.putExtra(BookmarksActivity.LOCATION_ID,locationID);
intent.putExtra(BookmarksActivity.ROUTE_ID, -1)
intent.putExtra(BookmarksActivity.BOOKMARK_TYPE,1);
((Activity) context).setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
((Activity) context).finish();
```

also:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(BookmarksActivity.ROUTE_ID,routeID);
intent.putExtra(BookmarksActivity.LOCATION_ID,-1);
intent.putExtra(BookmarksActivity.BOOKMARK_TYPE,2);
((Activity) context).setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
((Activity) context).finish();
```

then in your result:

```
if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_BOOKMARKS_ACTIVITY)
{
    if(data != null)
    {
        int temp = data.getIntExtra(BookmarksActivity.LOCATION_ID, -1);
    int temp2 = data.getIntExtra(BookmarksActivity.ROUTE_ID, -1);

        if(temp != -1)
        {
            int locationId = data.getIntExtra(BookmarksActivity.LOCATION_ID, 1);
            Log.i("BBB",    locationId + "");
            myDataSource.open();
            com.zayed.zma_at3.model.Location savedLocation = myDataSource.getLocationByID(locationId);
            createMarkerOnLocation(savedLocation.getTitle(),savedLocation.getLat(),savedLocation.getLng());
        }
        else if(temp2 != -1)
        {
            int routeId = data.getIntExtra(BookmarksActivity.ROUTE_ID, 1);
            myDataSource.open();
            Route route = myDataSource.getRouteById(routeId);
            route.setLocationPoints(myDataSource.getPointsByRouteId(routeId));

            // Draw line on map
            for(com.zayed.zma_at3.model.Location p : route.getLocationPoints())
                {
                    Log.i("BBB",  route.getId() +" "+ p.getId() + " " + p.getLat()
                            + " " + p.getLng() + "");
                }
        }
    }
```